# Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'babel-core' at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)

Tags: babel-core

> Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'babel-core'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)

sharing package.json file

```
 "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",

    "cli-color": "^2.0.0",
    "colors": "^1.3.3",
    "diff": "^4.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "google-spreadsheet-to-json": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-template": "^5.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.6",
    "i": "^0.3.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "modernizr": "^3.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "npm": "^6.12.0",
    "npm-check-updates": "^3.1.25",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "puppeteer": "^1.14.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-ga": "^2.4.1",
    "react-graceful-unmount": "^1.0.7",
    "react-iframe": "^1.8.0",
    "react-loadable": "^5.3.1",
    "react-onclickoutside": "^6.7.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-slick": "^0.25.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "scriptjs": "^2.5.8",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "url-loader": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-browser-plugin": "^1.0.20",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "yargs": "^14.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.6.4",

    "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.6.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-minify": "^0.3.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^6.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "del": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint": "^4.18.2",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-awspublish": "^3.3.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^7.0.1",
    "gulp-bump": "^3.1.3",
    "gulp-git": "^2.9.0",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-prompt": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "modernizr-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "prettier-eslint": "^8.8.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "install": "npm run install-webpack-dev-server",

    "install-webpack-dev-server": "npm install -g webpack webpack-dev-server",
    "prebuild": "gulp clean && gulp bump",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "prepublish": "npm run build",
    "publish": "gulp publish && gulp git",
    "push": "npm run publish && gulp sync",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --progress --inline --hot --config webpack.dev.js",
    "split": "gulp react-split"
  }
}
```